# Dash Plotly transform into an absolute value for hovertemplate

Tags: python, hover, plotly, plotly-dash

For my Dash Plotly graph, I want to remove the negative sign in my graph hover label. How do I make it into an abs value? And what is this text formatting called? Official documentation is appreciated!

`hovertemplate="%{base:.2f}"`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- you can use **meta** to hold the absolute value
- then use **meta** in the **hovertemplate**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
        "x": pd.date_range("1-jan-2021", periods=10),
        "Positive": np.random.uniform(1, 5, 10),
        "Negative": np.random.uniform(-5, -3, 10),})

go.Figure(
    [go.Bar(x=df["x"], y=df[t], meta=df[t].abs(), name=t, hovertemplate="%{meta:.2f}") for t in ["Positive", "Negative"]]
).update_layout(hovermode="x unified")
```

[image]